# Selecting from selected features by subquery in ArcMap Query Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.6, query-builder

I've set up a Model in ArcGIS ModelBuilder (ArcMap 10.6) which select some rows of table "Rivers". Then i want to select the River with the Max-Value of Field "Diff" out of the selected Rows (not the whole Dataset). I tried to use "Select Layer by Attribute" with the following Expression

```
"Diff"= (Select MAX("Diff") FROM "Rivers")
```

it looks like the subquery selects "MAX" from the whole Dataset and not from my selection.

How do I extract the Max-Value from my selection?

Comment: The table is a shapefile, file geodatabase or what format? See: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/sql-reference-for-query-expressions-used-in-arcgis.htm#GUID-F5320DB5-4E54-4D49-BF31-A58F5379ED9F

Comment: I've come across this issue before, I don't believe the subquery honours a selection. You need to export your selection to a temporary dataset in the same workspace then subquery that.

Comment: The table is a Feature Layer in a File Geodatabase so Subquery is already running, but not just on the selection.
My problem with an export is that i need this subquery in a model, so it would produce 20'000 datasets

Comment: Why would exporting a selection create 20,000 datasets? Did you mean 20,000 rows in a single dataset?

Comment: I have to process 20'000 different selections, on every selection will the subquery run

Comment: What is creating the selections? Is it a spatial query or an attribute query, if attribute (e.g. some admin area code) consider pre-processing that as a group by in a summary tool? I think you need to edit your question, provide screen shots of your model, example data, example of how you are selecting as it sounds like you might need to rethink your workflow and possibly abandon modelbuilder for a scripting approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. I've learn't that a subquery can't handle a predefined selection. I solved it now with a little script that calculates the max-Value separately and use this value as a parameter in the main-query. So both querys can deal with the preselection and it runs.

Answer (score 0):

In your "Select Layer by Attribute" for your sub_query change the *Selection type* parameter to **SUBSET_SELECTION**[image: SUBSET_SELECTION]